# Create a customized android.app.Application in Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new in Cordova plugin. I'm wondering if it's possible to create a customized android.app.Application in my plugin in Android? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to do this, but you need to add a name reference to your application class in the `<application>` element of the `AndroidManifest.xml`. 
Once way to do this is to use an `after_prepare` hook script to apply it to the manifest after each Cordova prepare operation. For example:

**plugin.xml**

```
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    id="cordova-plugin-myplugin" 
    version="1.0.0">

  <name>My Plugin</name>

  <platform name="android">

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="MyPlugin" >
        <param name="android-package" value="my.package.MyPlugin"/>
      </feature>
    </config-file>

    <js-module name="MyPlugin" src="myplugin.js">
        <clobbers target="MyPlugin"/>
    </js-module>

    <source-file src="MyPlugin.java" target-dir="src/my/package" />
    <source-file src="MyApplication.java" target-dir="src/my/package" />

    <hook type="after_prepare" src="add_application_name.js" />

  </platform>
</plugin>
```

**add_application_name.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

module.exports = function(context) {

  var APPLICATION_CLASS = "my.package.MyApplication";

  var fs = context.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
      path = context.requireCordovaModule('path');

  var platformRoot = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android');
  var manifestFile = path.join(platformRoot, 'AndroidManifest.xml');

  if (fs.existsSync(manifestFile)) {
    fs.readFile(manifestFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error('Unable to find AndroidManifest.xml: ' + err);
      }

      if (data.indexOf(APPLICATION_CLASS) == -1) {
        var result = data.replace(/<application/g, '<application android:name="' + APPLICATION_CLASS + '"');
        fs.writeFile(manifestFile, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
          if (err) throw new Error('Unable to write into AndroidManifest.xml: ' + err);
        })
      }
    });
  }
};
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
package my.package;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    public static final String TAG = "MyApplication";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        // DO SOME STUFF
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a try. Another question. If it's possible to pass some values through plugin.xml to my java file, for example, MyApplication.java?

Comment: Your second question doesn't have an easy answer. Assuming you want to use the values in `onCreate()` of your application class, the Cordova environment has not initialised at this point, so any parsing of XML must be done from Java. plugin.xml is not copied into `platforms/android` so you'd need a self-reference to specify it as a source file which should be copied to the platform project. You could then parse and read values from it in your application class.

Comment: Which variable is `appClass` in your hook? It throws an error and it seems it's not defined in the code snippet.

Comment: @SolveSoul It's a typo: should be `APPLICATION_CLASS ` - fixed in the example snippet

Comment: @ZhouHao I know it's been a while since you last asked this but one way to pass data to your custom app class would be to use the BuildConfig. This is a special class on Android that is generated on build time and you can use gradle to set those variables. See more details on how to accomplish it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code). You would then create a .gradle file on your plugin that contains the variables you need and on your application class you would access them using BuildConfig.NAME_OF_VAR.